# Javascript отключен - что делать?

Tags: javascript, php

Делал, делал проект, оказалось, что есть люди, которые отключают javascript в бразузере. Т.е., в каждом проекте,получается, необходимо определять, *а не выключен ли яваскрипт* ?? и всегда иметь платформу для безскриптового отображения и взаимодействия сайта. что за фигня? Я полдня потратил, чтобы будущий проект мог работать без скриптов. Это ужас. Что на этот счет скажут настоящие погромисты? ))

(У меня на каждой кнопке вызывается соответствующий скрипт)

Comment: Оказывается я -- дибилоид. А я-то и не знал. Спасибо за информацию.

Да, а ещё у меня Adlock Plus установлен. Это вносит какие-то коррективы в диагноз?

Comment: @alexlz: и я :-) А ещё у меня referrer отключен и cookies автоматически стираются. (И я расстрелял бы тупой пилой тех горе-программистов, которые опираются на referrer.)

Comment: Ребята, я просто вам завидую, у меня диагноз еще хуже...

Comment: @alexlz, вы что,правда дибилоид?

Comment: Видимо так. Правда js не совсем отключён -- стоит NoScript, но вряд ли это существенно меняет Ваш диагноз, доктор.

Comment: @alexlz, взломайте мой сайт (в феврале писал его), и тогда поговорим. хорошо? http://cassandra.besaba.com/

Comment: @Deus я точно безнадёжен. Взламывать сайты я не умею совсем. Похоже, мне пора на свалку.

Comment: @VladD надо реферер отключать только с других доменов, а не с того-же самого.

Comment: @eicto, у меня серверный скрипт делает перенаправление, используя HTTP_REFERER. Если ВладД отключит у себя referer, скрипт на сервере не будет работать что ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сайт-таки должен нормально работать без яваскрипта. По крайней мере, выводить основную информацию. Это просто правило хорошего тона как много лет назад было правилом составлять страницы в разных кодировках, делать заглушки под флэш или предупреждать о большом объеме информации.

Расслабьтесь.

Проверять специально ничего не надо: `<noscript>` уже за вас придуман.

N.B. переделывать функционал совершенно не обязательно. Но совершенно обязательно обеспечить работу сайта, чтобы ничего не глюкнуло и не вылетело. Авторизация, например.

Comment: @knes, как в око глядел! Именно авторизация и интересовала. У меня же ж на кнопке "сабмит" - должна, по идее вызываться функция проверки, а 
вдруг? :))))

Comment: Я вообще изначально поставил <noscript>fuck you</noscript> А потом задумался...

Comment: @Deus: Вообще-то, если у вас проверки делаются лишь на стороне клиента, не обижайтесь, но вы написали фигню. Это полбеды, если клиент без JS не сможет попасть на сайт, а вот script-kiddie с telnet'ом может отправить любую невалидированную информацию и положить сервер.

Comment: @VladD, вы несете ахинею для меня. Я воспитан в духе консерватизма. Сделал большой портал и <i>вдруг</i> понял,что без скриптов половина сайта будет недоступна пользователям. Спасибо все учителям jQuery,и javascript за то, что они научили меня использовать могущество ajax-превосходству, однако, я просто обязан сойти на уровень ниже и делать a-la девяностые годы...

Comment: @VladD, извиняюсь, у меня на сервере тоже идет обработка данных, а что такое это ваш script-kiddie?

Comment: @Deus: Угу, а некоторые считают, что у всех есть Flash. А некоторые считают, что у всех IE. А некоторые считают, что у всех разрешены прости господи ActiveX-объекты. Вы должны понять, что бывают пользователи, которые отходят от настроек по умолчанию.

Посмотрите, как ведут себя *хорошие* сайты без JS. Если найдёте `<noscript>fuck you</noscript>` на сайте из первой тысячи по посещаемости, с меня ящик пива.

Браузер называется user agent'ом не зря: ему пофиг, что на ajax'е удобно подгружать контент. Ему не пофиг только то, хочется ли это юзеру.

Comment: насчет <noscript>fuck you</noscript> не знаю, но facebook в elinks не работает. и

     <noscript>
        <div id="no_js_box">
            <h2>В вашем браузере отключен JavaScript.</h2>
            <p>Пожалуйста, включите поддержку JavaScript в вашем браузере или установите браузер с поддержкой JavaScript, чтобы зарегистрироваться на Facebook.</p>
        </div>
    </noscript>

тянет хотя-бы на бутылку кока-колы ?

Comment: @VladD, vk.com: "JavaScript and Cookies need to be supported in order to use the site. To be able to use all of the site's functions, download and install one of the following browsers:" Не совсем fuck you, но близко.

Comment: @dzhioev: Окей, предыдущим двум ораторам по бутылке кока-колы (или какой там правильный немецкий аналог) :)

Answer (score 5):

Любое веб-приложение должно выполнять свою функцию исключительно на сервере. Всё, что выполняется на стороне клиента - делается исключительно для удобства пользователя (предварительная валидация форм, смена содержимого без обновления страницы и прочее), т.е. идёт надстройкой.

Но современные примитивные сайты делаются в стиле "лишь бы у заказчика работало", и, как следствие, возникают подобные вопросы у "бедных крутых веб-кодеров".

С другой стороны, "правильная" разработка стоит больших денег, которых у заказчика может просто не быть. В этом случае приходится экономить за счет урезания функционала приложения в режиме `noscript`. Но сайт в этом случае все равно должен выполнять свою функцию - предоставлять информацию.

Вот пара советов:

- Если событие клика по какому-то
  элементу возможно лишь при включенных
  скриптах у пользователя - то такой
  элемент необходимо скрыть по
  умолчанию (`display: none;` или
  `visibility: hidden;` - выбирать
  методом тыка ;)), а отображать после
  загрузки страницы тем же скриптом.
- Аналогично следует поступать с
  "галереями" и "слайдерами" - кнопки
  управления по умолчанию должны быть
  скрыты.
- Если скриптами вы скрываете часть
  текста под неким "читать далее", то
  по умолчанию текст должен быть виден
  весь, а "урезаться" уже скриптом.
- Если на картинки вы ставите
  какие-либо скрипты отображения их
  увеличенной версии в модальном окне -
  как правило прописывается ссылка на
  эту самую увеличенную версию. Не
  помешает дописать к такой ссылке
  свойство `target="_blank"`.

И т.д., и т.п.

Для примера приведу пару скриншотов - с [включенными](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4736W.jpg) скриптами и c [отключенными](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNaqE.jpg). Как видно из скриншотов, без скриптов пользователь лишается возможности сделать заказ, но вполне может просмотреть сайт как каталог - что намного лучше, чем приведенный пример `<noscript>fuck you</noscript>`.

Answer (score 3):

делайте редирект на страницу с сообщением как включать явускрипт и почему это необходимо, код в <head>

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=страница-сообщения-о-необходимости-включить-яву-скрипт.html"></noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

С этим ничего не поделаешь. Помимо этого, ещё есть люди  с ограниченными возможностями, они тоже не смогут пользоваться вашим сайтом.

Пользователей с отключенным JS, даже на очень крупных проектах, менее 0.5%. Так что выбирать вам, либо показать им табличку, как включить JS, либо проработать сценарий без него.

Comment: @RubaXa, я делаю сайт для людей, которые будут давать деньги для людей с ограниченными возможностями. Вы меня поняли? Я задал весьма адекватный вопрос. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Если вы серьезно, без сарказма, то советую обратить внимание не на JS, а на http://wcag.ru/guidelines/wcag20.html

Comment: @RubaXa,без сарказма, делаю независимый сайт для людей, которые хотят вернуть людям понятие взаимопонимания, любви и .. долго объяснять. Ну, вы меня поняли...

Answer (score 0):

а что может js проверять в форме авторизации кроме как заполнено ли поле?
ну, я в плане адекватности.

Comment: Еще скрипт проверяет адекватность введенных символов.

Answer (score 0):

Это считается нормальным что люди так делают, поэтому и есть такое определение как graceful degradation(отказоустойчивость), хотя этим никогда не забивал голову(грех) 
:)

Comment: @gold, исходя из принятых ответов и комментариев, уже давно иду другим путем - делаю проект ПОЛНОСТЬЮ без использования скриптов, а на готовую рабочую страницу прикручиваю обработчики событий ( для красоты :)).

Comment: Не ленивый :) На самом деле это хорошо, честно не видел что бы кто то заморачивался этим вопросом, на будущее буду знать )